# Window.Element is undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I have a piece of code in a library that uses the window.Element object. It tries to access it by doing Element.prototype which throws an error of

> "cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined"

This only happens with Salesforce **LockerService** turned on. I would like this to still work while LockerService is still on. I was wondering if anyone has encountered such issue and have a workaround?

Here's a sample code from the library:

```
var matchesMethod = ( function() {
  //starts to break here
  var ElemProto = Element.prototype;
  // check for the standard method name first
  if ( ElemProto.matches ) {
    return 'matches';
  }
  // check un-prefixed
  if ( ElemProto.matchesSelector ) {
    return 'matchesSelector';
  }
  // check vendor prefixes
  var prefixes = [ 'webkit', 'moz', 'ms', 'o' ];

  for ( var i=0; i < prefixes.length; i++ ) {
    var prefix = prefixes[i];
    var method = prefix + 'MatchesSelector';
    if ( ElemProto[ method ] ) {
      return method;
    }
  }
})();
```

UPDATE: Adding a screenshot of what's currently available on the window object.

[image]

Comment: As per the Locker Service API docs looks like window.element should be supported .Sounds like a bug to me .http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureWindow.app?aura.mode=DEV

Comment: Thanks @MohithShrivastava yeah, afterScriptsLoaded, I added a debugger to see what window.Element or Element would return and it's undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have added support for window.Element in the Spring'17 release. We are currently working on bringing it to Winter'17 release as well.

Comment: [Update]This should be fixed now. Please try you scenario and let us know if its still broken.

Comment: I'm still getting this error in my browser console. Pls advise how to fix it.